# OWIN ASP.NET - Cant generate Access Token using Refresh Token if Access Token is expired

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, oauth, owin

When I try to generate an Access Token using the Refresh Token before Access Token expires, the system generate a new one and everything is okey. But if the Access Token is expired, the request return `invalid_grant`.

Isn't the `Validated()` method from `GrantRefreshToken` generate the Access Token using the identity I stored in the dictionary from the previously Access Token?

And how can I block clients from asking for new Access Token using the same Refresh Token if the last one isn't expired yet?

Here is my code:

**Startup.cs:**

```
public partial class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions()
        {
            AllowInsecureHttp = true,

            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/token"),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),

            Provider = new OAuthProvider(),
            RefreshTokenProvider = new RefreshTokenProvider()
        });
        app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions());
        app.UseWebApi(config);
    }
}
```

**OAuthProvider.cs:**

```
public class OAuthProvider : OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider
{
    public override Task ValidateClientAuthentication(OAuthValidateClientAuthenticationContext context)
    {
        context.Validated();
        return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
    }

    public override Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
    {
        if (context.UserName == "admin" && context.Password == "123456")
        {
            var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(context.Options.AuthenticationType);
            claimsIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, context.UserName));
            claimsIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Admin"));

            var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(claimsIdentity, null);
            context.Validated(ticket);
        }
        return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
    }

    public override Task GrantRefreshToken(OAuthGrantRefreshTokenContext context)
    {
        context.Validated(context.Ticket);
        return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
    }
}
```

**RefreshTokenProvider.cs:**

```
public class RefreshTokenProvider : AuthenticationTokenProvider
{
    private static ConcurrentDictionary<string, AuthenticationTicket> _refreshTokens = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, AuthenticationTicket>();

    public override Task CreateAsync(AuthenticationTokenCreateContext context)
    {
        var guid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        _refreshTokens.TryAdd(guid, context.Ticket);

        context.SetToken(guid);
        return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
    }

    public override Task ReceiveAsync(AuthenticationTokenReceiveContext context)
    {
        if (_refreshTokens.TryRemove(context.Token, out AuthenticationTicket ticket))
        {
            context.SetTicket(ticket);
        }
        return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
    }
}
```

Sorry for bad english, I hope you understand!

**EDIT:**

Well, I modified the code to implement Database support and set the Refresh Token expiration to 5 minutes. The expiration is small for testing purposes.

Here is the result:

**OAuthProvider.cs:**

```
public class OAuthProvider : OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider
{
    public override Task ValidateClientAuthentication(OAuthValidateClientAuthenticationContext context)
    {
        context.Validated();
        return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
    }

    public override Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            var account = AccountRepository.Instance.GetByUsername(context.UserName);
            if (account != null && Global.VerifyHash(context.Password, account.Password))
            {
                var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(context.Options.AuthenticationType);
                claimsIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, account.Username));
                claimsIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("DriverId", account.DriverId.ToString()));

                var newTicket = new AuthenticationTicket(claimsIdentity, null);
                context.Validated(newTicket);
            }
        }
        catch { }

        return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
    }

    public override Task GrantRefreshToken(OAuthGrantRefreshTokenContext context)
    {
        context.Validated();
        return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
    }
}
```

**RefreshTokenProvider.cs:**

```
public class RefreshTokenProvider : AuthenticationTokenProvider
{
    public override Task CreateAsync(AuthenticationTokenCreateContext context)
    {
        var refreshToken = new TokenModel()
        {
            Subject = context.Ticket.Identity.Name,
            Token = GenerateToken(),
            IssuedUtc = DateTime.UtcNow,
            ExpiresUtc = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(5)
        };

        context.Ticket.Properties.IssuedUtc = refreshToken.IssuedUtc;
        context.Ticket.Properties.ExpiresUtc = refreshToken.ExpiresUtc;

        refreshToken.Ticket = context.SerializeTicket();

        try
        {
            TokenRepository.Instance.Insert(refreshToken);
            context.SetToken(refreshToken.Token);
        }
        catch { }

        return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
    }

    public override Task ReceiveAsync(AuthenticationTokenReceiveContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            var refreshToken = TokenRepository.Instance.Get(context.Token);
            if (refreshToken != null)
            {
                if (TokenRepository.Instance.Delete(refreshToken))
                {
                    context.DeserializeTicket(refreshToken.Ticket);
                }
            }
        }
        catch { }

        return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
    }

    private string GenerateToken()
    {
        HashAlgorithm hashAlgorithm = new SHA256CryptoServiceProvider();

        byte[] byteValue = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N"));
        byte[] byteHash = hashAlgorithm.ComputeHash(byteValue);

        return Convert.ToBase64String(byteHash);
    }
}
```

Thanks for the support!

Comment: What does the client request look like? Is it something like *grant_type=refresh_token&client_id=xxxxxx&refresh_token=xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxx*?

Comment: @RuardvanElburg For testing purposes I didn't implement client id yet. It looks like: `grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=xxxx‌​xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-‌​xxxxx`. And the credentials request looks like: `grant_type=password&username=username&password=password`

Comment: Can you include the client code you use to call the refresh token?

Comment: @RuardvanElburg I dont have.. Im testing with Postman.

Comment: The response is 'invalid_grant', which means that you are not sending the right information. A refresh_token is expected to be send in a *POST* message with the parameters in the *body*.

Comment: Im doing that.. But it doesn't work if the access token is expired. Isn't the objetive of refresh token to generate a new access token when it expired?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the refresh token has the same expiration time as the access token. So you'll need to extend the expiration of the refresh token:

```
public override Task CreateAsync(AuthenticationTokenCreateContext context)
{
    var form = context.Request.ReadFormAsync().Result;
    var grantType = form.GetValues("grant_type");

    if (grantType[0] != "refresh_token")
    {
        ...

        // One day
        int expire = 24 * 60 * 60;
        context.Ticket.Properties.ExpiresUtc = new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(expire));
    }
    base.Create(context);
}
```

-- Update --

I've updated the code to answer the question in your comment. It's more than you've asked for. But I think it will help to explain.

It all depends on the requirement and chosen strategy. To explain the code:

Each time an access token is issued you will also hit this piece of code which will add a refresh token. In this strategy I will issue a new refresh token only when grant_type is not 'refresh_token'. This means that at some point the refresh token expires and the user has to login again.

In the example the user has to login every day again. But if the user logs in before the refresh_token expires, a new refresh token will be issued. That way the refresh token has an absolute expiration time, forcing the user to login at least once a day.

If you want 'sliding expiration', you can add a refresh token every time you issue an access token. Please note that the user may never have to login again, unless the refresh token expires before refreshing.

In any case I wouldn't block users from creating access tokens when grant_type is not refresh_token. Since that is user interaction. The access token has a very limited window (think of hours or minutes, not days), so it will expire soon enough. You do not want to validate an access token each time you receive it in a header, since this means you'll need to check the database for each call.

Instead think of a strategy to invalidate 'old' refresh tokens. You could save the hashed version of the last refresh token in the database. If it doesn't match then respond with an 'invalid_grant' error.

Comment: Yep, you're right.. Thank you! One more question: actually clients can create multiple Access Tokens, every time with a new Refresh Token, but can exist multiple Access Tokens for the same user at the same time. Is there any way to block clients from creating new Access Tokens if the last one isnt expired yet?

Comment: @JuliánPera Does this answer your questions?

Comment: Thank you, you're giving me a lot of help. You're right, the access token has a very limited window. I updated the original post, with the new code and some questions. Can you take a look?

Comment: The original question has been answered and the new questions are out of scope. So I suggest you accept the answer and create a new question.